# bash - escape variable SSH command without altering it

Tags: bash, variables, command-line, escaping

I am running a command in a bash script that uses the content of a file as an argument. Here a simplified example:

```
USER=$(<$fileA)
PASSWORD=$(<$fileB)
wget -u $USER -p $PASSWORD
```

However, the content of the file can be set to any value by the user. I assume I need to escape this, but I don't know how to do that, especially in a way that $PASSWORD will NOT be altered. Otherwise the password will obviously not work.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't use the variable name `USER` -- it's prepopulated by the shell with the current user's username, and changing it may confuse anything that expects it to have that value. There are a bunch of all-caps variables with special meanings, so it's best to use lower- or mixed-case names for your variables, to avoid possible conflicts.

Comment: If you execute that line, then the username and password are exposed to anyone who happens to be logged on to your machine (through /proc/<pid>/cmdline`, for example, or with even less work through the `ps` command). With curl, you can create a less insecure command-line: `echo user|cat "$fileA" "$fileB"|paste -sd:|curl -K- http://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably simply need to add quotes around the variables.

```
wget -u "$USER" -p "$PASSWORD"
```

If you happen to capture a newline at the end of the variable, you may want to strip it with:

```
wget -u "${USER%$'\n'}" -p "${PASSWORD%$'\n'}"
```

The `${var}` syntax is equivalent to `$var` but curly braces allows to manipulate variables with bash. By adding `%$'\n'` before the ending curly brace, the `%` means to remove the text `$'\n'`, which means removing the trailing newline, if any.

In the worst case scenario, you may get newline and carriage returns (probably if the files were generated by a text editor in Windows), but you can also deal with it:

```
wget -u "${USER%%[$'\n'$'\r']*}" -p "${PASSWORD%%[$'\n'$'\r']*}"
```

This time around, the searched text is `[$'\n'$'\r']*` which is means "the first newline (`\n`) or carriage return (`\r`) and everything after" and the `%%` operator means "remove the longest sequence at the end".

Comment: The last one (for DOS/Windows line endings) doesn't work -- the pattern `[$'\n'$'\r']` only matches a single character (either carriage return or newline), not a sequence of them. And it's actually a glob pattern not a regex, so you can't just add `*` to the end to match multiple instances. You could do it with `extglob`...

Comment: And I don't think `"${USER%$'\n'}"` will ever do anything since [command substitution `$(...)` strips trailing newlines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for the correction. I edited the answer.

Comment: @PesaThe You’re right but ultimately I don’t know if the OP will use `$()` to capture the input, in which case the answer may be of interest. Plus it makes the transition easier to the following parameter substitution.

Comment: @vdavid Also care with `[$'\n'$'\r']*`. It doesn't remove trailing newlines or carriage returns. It is **not** a regex and in fact it removes **anything** up to the first `\n` or `\r` present in the string. Try it for: `var=$'abc\ndef\n123\n'`. You could use `extglob`, as Gordon suggested: `${var%%+([$'\n\r'])}`.

Comment: @PesaThe You are right about the potential mistake if newlines are inserted in the middle, however what are the chances that a username or a password has newlines? Moreover extglob is (usually) not enabled by default, and while I could suggest the OP to enable it, it may break other scripts that are already running correctly and I don't want him/her to deal with that.